# AngularJS $routerProvider not working properly in node-webkit

Tags: angularjs, node-webkit

I'm building a desktop application with node-webkit and angular. I have been using version 1.0.7 of angular, but I need to update to take advantage of improvements to the framework. Unfortunately, the new `ngRoute` module doesn't seem to be working properly whereas I had no problems with routing previously.

Using the `angular-seed` boilerplate as an example, when the app loads up it shows view1, but clicking on the links for view1 and view2 has seemingly no effect. I have verified it works fine when served as a webpage in a browser, but in the node-webkit environment it fails.

I did discover that if I comment out the `otherwise` option for `$routeProvider` that the address bar shows `index.html#/C:/view1` instead of `app/index.html#/view1`, and of course then neither view1 nor view2 is shown, and clicking on the view1 and view2 links still has no effect. It seems that the links are possibly being interpreted incorrectly? If so, how should they be formatted? I've played around with a bunch of combinations to no effect.

`app.js`

```
'use strict';


// Declare app level module which depends on filters, and services
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'myApp.filters',
  'myApp.services',
  'myApp.directives',
  'myApp.controllers'
]).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/view1', {templateUrl: 'partials/partial1.html', controller: 'MyCtrl1'});
  $routeProvider.when('/view2', {templateUrl: 'partials/partial2.html', controller: 'MyCtrl2'});
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
}]);
```

`index.html`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My AngularJS App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"/>
</head>
<body>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#/view1">view1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/view2">view2</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div ng-view></div>

  <div>Angular seed app: v<span app-version></span></div>

  <!-- In production use:
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  -->
  <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/services.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
  <script src="js/filters.js"></script>
  <script src="js/directives.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work. I used the same strategy used in the Angular documentation to make the ngRoute example code work in plunkr. I can't say I exactly understand why it didn't work using the stock `angular-seed` configuration. If anyone has insight, I'd like to hear it.

The modified `index.html` and `app.js` files should look like this:

`app.js`

```
'use strict';


// Declare app level module which depends on filters, and services
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'myApp.filters',
  'myApp.services',
  'myApp.directives',
  'myApp.controllers'
]).
config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/view1', {templateUrl: 'partials/partial1.html', controller: 'MyCtrl1'});
  $routeProvider.when('/view2', {templateUrl: 'partials/partial2.html', controller: 'MyCtrl2'});
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
  // configure html5 to get links working on node-webkit
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

`index.html`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My AngularJS App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"/>
  <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular/angular-route.js"></script>  
  <script type="text/javascript">
  //this is here to make node-webkit work with AngularJS routing
  angular.element(document.getElementsByTagName('head')).append(angular.element('<base href="' + window.location.pathname + '" />'));
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="view1">view1</a></li>
    <li><a href="view2">view2</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div ng-view></div>

  <div>Angular seed app: v<span app-version></span></div>

  <!-- In production use:
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  -->
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/services.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
  <script src="js/filters.js"></script>
  <script src="js/directives.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that in this mode, `index.html` is no longer part of the URL, so if you reload, nw tries to reload a file that doesn't exist (e.g. `/path/to/app/view1`). You need to manually update it to `/path/to/app/index.html`. It would be nice if you could make nw go back to the main page on reload, but I so far don't see an option for making that happen.

Late breaking news: It was due to a [bug in Angular 1.2.0](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4680), which has since been resolved. The `angular-seed` simply has not yet been updated to the most recent version.

Comment: do you mind sharing your package json file I followed your setup and I get this error NSWorkspace failed to open URL unsafe:app://toubaradio/views/playlist/42991671

Comment: So `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` and AngularJS version upgrade fixed it. Right. I can't see any differences in your index.html. If there are none I suggest you remove that. Sometime we are in hurry and need to read fast so any extraneous stuff just hinders.